# How to add tag to singular test in dbt

Tags: tags, dbt, except

I have several singular tests (my own written `except_<model_name>_test.sql` SQL files) which are testing ***EXCEPT*** statement between source and target tables:

```
select src.* from src
EXCEPT
select tgt.* from tgt
```

So, I added in dbt `dbt_project.yml` this line:

```
tests:
  +tags:
    - except
```

and add to each test file (`except_<model_name>_test.sql`) these  lines:

```
{{ config(
    tags=["except"]
) }}
```

But when running

```
dbt test -s tag:except
```

It runs all tests, why not only these several with tags?